# Dificuldade em Loops While e Foreach

Tags: php, mysql, loop

Estou estudando php ha pouco tempo então não entendi corretamente as estrutura dos laços como while e foreach gostaria que alguem me explicasse o porque esse while não exibe nada, e quando tento usar foreach da erro. Desde já agradeço a compreensão e paciencia.

```
<div id="resultado">
  <table width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr align="center">
        <th align="center"class="filter-match" data-placeholder="">ID|</th>

        <th align="center"class="filter-match" data-placeholder="">|Cliente|</th>

        <th align="center"class="filter-match" data-placeholder="">|Data Retorno|</th>

        <th align="center" data-placeholder="">|Nome do Contato|</th>  

        <th height="24" data-placeholder="">|Assunto</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      </div>

<tbody>



  <tr align="center" >
<?php 


    $acompanhamento = mysql_query("SELECT id_cliente, cliente_nome, data_ret, nome, mensagem FROM acompanhamento 
    WHERE data_ret = '".date('Y-m-d')."' ");
   while ($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($acompanhamento)){
       echo
                           $exibe["id_cliente"];
                            $exibe["nome"];
                            $exibe["mensagem"];
                            $exibe["cliente_nome"];
                            $exibe["data_ret"];

   };


    echo   $id_cliente;    
           $cliente_nome; 
           $data_ret;      
           $nome;          
           $mensagem;  






    ?>  


    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>



//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<div id="resultado">
 <table width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr align="center">
        <th align="center"class="filter-match" data-placeholder="">ID|</th>

    <th align="center"class="filter-match" data-placeholder="">|Cliente|</th>

    <th align="center"class="filter-match" data-placeholder="">|Data Retorno|</th>

    <th align="center" data-placeholder="">|Nome do Contato|</th>  

    <th height="24" data-placeholder="">|Assunto</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  </div>

<tbody>



  <tr align="center" >
<?php 


    $acompanhamento = mysql_query("SELECT id_cliente, cliente_nome, data_ret, nome, mensagem FROM acompanhamento 
    WHERE data_ret = '".date('Y-m-d')."' ");
   $exibe = mysql_fetch_array($acompanhamento)
   foreach mysql_fetch_array($acompanhamento) as $value)
            {
       echo
                           $exibe["id_cliente"];
                            $exibe["nome"];
                            $exibe["mensagem"];
                            $exibe["cliente_nome"];
                            $exibe["data_ret"];

   };


    echo   $id_cliente;    
           $cliente_nome; 
           $data_ret;      
           $nome;          
           $mensagem;  






    ?>  


    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Antes de usar o looping dá um var_dump(mysql_fetch_array($acompanhamento));

Comment: Se retornou algo na query irá exibir. Lembrando que as funções mysql_* foram descontinuadas na versão atual do php

Answer (score 0):

1º Confira se você fez corretamente a conexão com o banco

2º Use aspas simples 
                            $exibe['id_cliente'];
                            $exibe['nome'];
                            $exibe['mensagem'];
                            $exibe['cliente_nome'];
                            $exibe['data_ret'];

3º coloque um echo qualquer dentro do repetidor para poder saber se está executando como deveria, talvez não está nem entrando no while.

4º Você fez 1 Echo e usou ponto e virgula depois de cada $exibe, somente é necessário ; na ultima variável.

Comment: O motivo provável de dar erro no Foreach,  é por que sua variavel $acompanhamento não deve estar recebendo nada.